# controllers not communicates in angular

Tags: angularjs, controller, communication

I'm trying to communicate from controller1 to controller2 with $broadcast/$emit and $on but they doesn't communicates and I don't get why.

The controllers are not in same files and there is no hierarchy parent/child.

controller1 :

```
    $scope.showDetail = function (data) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("event_detail", data);
        };
```

controller2 :

```
  $rootScope.$on('event_detail', function (event, args) {
        console.log(args);       
    });
```

I also tried to use $scope instead of $rootScope in both controllers.
I call the function showDetail in a ng-click in a table.

Comment: Are the both controllers active at the same time?

Comment: I added :    <div ng-controller="controller2"></div> in view1 and it's working.

Is there any other solutions to "activate" the controller2 ?

Comment: Use scope.$on with broadcast  on rootscope should work

Comment: It's working. Controllers2 needed to be active